# Create NUnit tests analogous to a MbUnit TestSuiteFixture

Tags: nunit, mbunit

Is it possible to achieve the same (or close to the same) functionality as a [MbUnit TestSuiteFixture](http://gallio.org/oldwiki/MbUnit/TestSuiteFixture.html) using NUnit? I need to generate sets of dynamic test cases and MbUnit's TestSuiteFixture is the only thing I have found so far that comes close to solving this need.